# Как сравнить текущие значение переменой с предыдущим?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть переменная `vlll` которая получает значение с инпута. Как сделать так чтобы например первый раз при проверки инпута например по клику она сохранила значение , а при второй проверке она сравнила первое значение со вторым , и если равно не равно что то там вывести ?

к инпуту обращаюсь вот так :

```
var vlll = $("#scanInput").val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Развёрнутый ответ предложения @NeedHate. При первой проверке можно сохранять «начальное» значение элемента в его `data-...` атрибуте, напр. так:

```
// по первому клику, например:
// var vlll = $("#scanInput").val();
$("#scanInput").data('initial', $("#scanInput").val());
```

Тогда при последующих сравнениях:

```
// по другому событию, не первому:
if( $("#scanInput").data('initial') == $("#scanInput").val()) {
    // равны
} else {
    // не равны
}
```

Можно много улучшать: кэшировать jQuery элемент; всё поместить в один обработчик - тогда первый вызов от последующих будет отличаться отсутствием значения в `.data('initial')`, или можно ещё ставить второе значение для отметки о не-первом вызове: `.data('notfirst', true)` и проверять его.

Answer (score 2):

Можно в тег добавить параметр data-storage, например. И допустим там будет data-storage="100". И сравнивать со значениями в этом параметре.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно также использовать замыкание. Ниже показан код на JavaScript

```
function getValue()
{
    "USE STRICT";

    var prev;

    return function () {
        "USE STRICT";

        var current = document.getElementById("task").value;

        if (current === prev) alert("They are equal");
        else alert("They are not equal");

        prev = current;

        return false;
    };
}

function init() {
    "USE STRICT";

    document.getElementById("theForm").onsubmit = getValue();
}

window.onload = init;
```